# What is the hardware address of my Webcam Mic?

Tags: sound, webcam, microphone

I know that the video is `/dev/video0` however I do not know how to find the hardware address of my mic. I know that it is not `hw:0,0` or any of those.

The output of `aplay --list-device` is:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The command I'm trying to find the address for is:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :inputlave=alsa://hw:0,0 :live-caching=300 :sout="#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv}"
```

The *inputlave=alsa://hw:0,0* I believe needs to be changed.

Comment: It is not clear for *which use* do you want the "address"; it can be different depending on the usage (for example, `/dev/video0` is a standard unix device file, `eth0` a network interface, `ata:2:00` a ATA bus device...)

Comment: @Rmano I added the command I'm trying to change.

Comment: I do not know `cvlv` --- probably you should dig there. I would try `hw:1,0` (card-device) or `hw:0,1` (device-subdevice), but it is a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
arecord --list-devices
```

and

```
arecord --list-pcms
```

for example... I don't think that ALSA capture devices have a standard unix device file associated. On my laptop:

```
(0)asus-rmano:~% arecord --list-devices      
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC269 Analog [ALC269 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have an audio capture device in `card 0`, `device 0`, `subdevice 0` (the internal mic). How this translate to an "address" depend on what you mean for it, and which app you use.

```
(0)asus-rmano:~% arecord --list-pcms     
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC269 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

For example to record something from the mic:

```
arecord  -D plughw -f S16_LE prova.wav
```

(stop with ctrl-c when done).

Comment: thank you, I did this and I got the following: 
    'card 1: VX800 [Microsoft LifeCam VX-800], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0'

So what would the format of my hw address be? hw:1,0?

Comment: Please add the results of commands to your question --- in comments it's almost impossible to read. You have a mic in `card 0, device 1, subdevice 0` (device-subdevice). How this translate to a "address" depend on the application you want to feed it in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to get a hardware address via `lspci -v` or `lsusb -v` - e.g.

`lspci -v` - sound card

> **00:1b.0** Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
>     Subsystem: *Device 3975*
>     Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
>     Memory at e1600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>     Capabilities: 
>     Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

`lsusb` - webcam

> Bus 002 Device 003: ID **5986:0292** Acer, Inc

You can also use `lshw`, with also has [a Graphical Interface](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lshw-gtk/).

Comment: The output of *lsusb -t* was: 
michaeljwjr@michaeljwjr-desk:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M


How do I translate that into an address? (trying to stream my audio)